# AttributeError: module 'grpc.experimental.aio' has no attribute 'StreamUnaryCall' - Google NLP API

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I want to run the script from Google NLP API:

https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/analyzing-entities

and I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myuser/Desktop/g.py", line 1, in <module>
    from google.cloud import language_v1
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/language_v1/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from google.cloud.language_v1.gapic import language_service_client
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/language_v1/gapic/language_service_client.py", line 24, in <module>
    import google.api_core.gapic_v1.client_info
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from google.api_core.gapic_v1 import method_async  # noqa: F401
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method_async.py", line 20, in <module>
    from google.api_core import general_helpers, grpc_helpers_async
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers_async.py", line 145, in <module>
    class _WrappedStreamUnaryCall(_WrappedUnaryResponseMixin, _WrappedStreamRequestMixin, aio.StreamUnaryCall):
AttributeError: module 'grpc.experimental.aio' has no attribute 'StreamUnaryCall'
[Finished in 1.6s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3', '-u', '/Users/myuser/Desktop/g.py']]
[dir: /Users/myuser/Desktop]
[path: /Users/myuser/opt/miniconda3/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin]
```

I also realized that it says in path "miniconda3" but I've uninstalled miniconda3.

Any help? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I realized this in an error from the library https://pypi.org/project/grpcio/

To solve this you need to install the latest version:

pip3 install grpcio==1.32.0

and you are done :)